# Creating user options / configuration for a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how to write a jQuery plugin BUT I had some funny ideas and developed some kind of "workaround" regardless my lack of skills :D I tried to Google a lot, but I can't realize the correct search string to find what I'm looking for.

Now, my plugin is "working" but I was wondering if somebody can enlighten me to make it look "better", with a properly written code.

You'll probably laugh after I show you what I've done so far , but please, take in mind I'm newbie and I'm just experimenting.

### http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/9za22/

In that jsfiddle you can see I didn't know how to handle "options" for calling dynamic content by the plugin like

```
var settings = $.extend({
            icono: "/images/icon_69.png",
            nombre: "Custom name"
        }, options );
```

(Although I don't know what this code does xD But I think that plugins' options should look like these)

but instead of that, I've used an `<i></i>` (HTML) element as "options holder" with `data-attributes` in which my script is "looking" for options in order to show another HTML element (let's call it an "alert") which contains dynamic content depending on the data stored in the attributes previously configured inside the `<i></i>` tag.
If there is not any `<i>` tag in the page, then no "alert" will be shown.

So
I was wondering if someone can give me a hand to write this "plugin" properly xD With options like [this kind of plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-options) does.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was just a newbie when I wrote this question xD